# Physical mailing address error when address personalization strings are included in Content Area

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

When validating emails, Marketing Cloud requires 'physical mailing address' AMPscript personalization strings to be present in the email.

If my address exists in a footer Content Area, for example:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="600" ID="Table5" Border=0>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <font face="verdana" size="1" color="#444444">This email was sent by:    
     <b>%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>%%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, 
     %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%<br><br>
     </font>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then if I use the following AMPscript code to include the footer Content Area in my HTML Paste email:

```
  %%=ContentArea('2092')=%%
```

When I validate the email, then I get the error:

> The email is missing a valid physical mailing address, which must be present on commercial emails per the federal CAN-SPAM Act. Please add a valid postal address in your account settings, or modify your email to include these fields, then you may resend your email.

I can obviously hard code the address personalization strings in each HTML Paste email, but I would prefer not to. Does anyone know of a workaround for this? It appears that Content Areas are not validated, which is rather strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That validation can be disabled by SFMC Support.

Occasionally we do something like this:

```
%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%%
 %%Member_Busname%% %%Member_Addr%% 
 %%Member_City%% %%Member_State%% %%Member_PostalCode%% 
 %%Member_Country%%
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was that the **Email Reply Address** wasn't validated yet (new MC org). 
Once you verify this, and you fill in everything under 'Company Information' (Account Settings), the problem should be solved.